# Google Play services installation on BlueStacks is failed: Incompatible with other application(s) using the same share user ID

Tags: android, google-play-services, bluestacks

Installation of Google Play services on BlueStacks is failed because of "Incompatible with other application(s) using the same share user ID." What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meet the same problem with you and I follow these steps.

step 1. Go to Settings > Apps (or Applications) > manage applications and select show All.
Then find Google Services Framework and click the Clear Data button.
Then click the Force Stop button. 
then uninstall GoogleServicesFramework.

step 2. Now install successfully Google play services.apk file

step 3. then install GoogleServicesFramework.apk file n restart bluestacks.

NOTE: Bluestacks Restart required. Go to taskbar right click on bluestacks and Quit.

step 4. start bluestacks n again sign in your gmail account. That's it! Enjoy!

P.S : You should Google some APK files Download links.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for a long time and the previous answer was largely unhelpful in solving it.  I have now found a solution, which I will share.  It is the same basic steps as the previous answer describes, but with a failsafe way to remove Google Services Framework and download links.

1. Use [Titanium Backup](http://matrixrewriter.com/android/files/TitaniumBackup_latest.apk) to remove Google Services Framework (Titanium Backup > Backup/Restore > Google Services Framework x.x.x > "Un-install !").
2. Install [Google Play Services](http://www.mediafire.com/?731nxlafqu1hcee) by running com.google.android.gms.apk.
3. Re-install [Google Services Framework](http://www.mediafire.com/?pd8j6q2yd28rr8r) by running GoogleServicesFramework_for_install.apk.
4. Restart BlueStacks (right-click the miniature BlueStacks icon in the taskbar and select Quit, then Start > "Start BlueStacks").

Thank you to [Giza Triton](https://getsatisfaction.com/people/giza_triton) for the information and .apk download links.

Comment: Titanium say: "Sorry, I could not acquire root privileges. This application will *not* work! Please verify that your ROM is rooted, and try again. This attempt was made using the "/system/xbin/su" command.